# Undo managed object deletion

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I set up the `NSUndoManager` on default MOC provided by MagicalRecord.

```
[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext].undoManager = [[NSUndoManager alloc] init];
```

When user swipes to delete in my table view I simply drop the object and persist changes to root context:

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
  NSManagedObject *model = [modelFromMainThread MR_inContext:localContext];
  [model MR_deleteEntityInContext:localContext];
}];
```

When user shakes device to undo the deletion I simply call `[defaultContext undo]`.

This works perfectly fine, the object resurrects and `NSFetchedResultsController` picks it up and adds it back to table view.

However the problem occurs when I edit resurrected object. It disappears again once I save it.

Is there anything I miss here to make it work properly?

Do I have to persist undo operation back to root context?

Comment: Yes, definitely persist. Essentially you should do the same as when deleting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should save object back to persistent storage when I undo persistent changes, otherwise the object will vanish on next merge.